# How do I implement the 'autoskip' feature in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4djWj.jpg) 


I am trying to use the autoSkip feature found here in the chart.js documentation:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=autoskip

The issue I am having is my x-axes labels are overlapping (see above example).
Everything I have read says this autoSkip feature should automatically skip overlapping labels. However, when setting this to both true or false, nothing seems to change in my chart.

```
 <Line
    data={this.state.chartData}
    options={{
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 2
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1, //sets the interval that our y axis counts by
            beginAtZero: false, //starts our graph at 0 if true
          },
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 88,
            autoskip: true,
            autoSkipPadding: 50
          },
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false
          },
          type: 'time',
          distribution: 'series',
          time: {
            unit: 'day',
            displayFormats: {
              day: 'MMM D',

            },
            tooltipFormat: 'MMM D h:mm a',
          },
        },
        ]
      },
      responsive: true, //lets us resize our chart
      maintainAspectRatio: true,  //lets us resize our chart
    }
    }

  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, please update to 2.9. Confirmed that the issue is resolved there.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6591

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your autoskip is in lower case where in the documentation its in camlcase (ie. autoSkip) - from my experience with Chartjs, I've found that it might make a difference to try and fix that and see if that does the trick

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just changed it back to 'autoSkip' looks like I'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing

```
distribution: series
```

to

```
distribution: linear
```

It looks to me like its trying to space the data evenly, despite the fact that you're missing data for 3 days (the weekend maybe?). It really shouldn't break your labels... but I bet the labels know there's enough space for n labels on the graph, but they don't realize that three of the labels are being squished together.

The default distribution is linear, so you could also just remove it. (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#scale-distribution)

Comment: Hi Chris,

I appreciate the response. Since this is a stock market app, and the stock exchange does not run on weekends, I went with a series distribution. Going Linear in this case would cause a large gap in my graph of empty data on the weekends.

Comment: I would still test for this and see if this is what is causing the issue... after all, until you know what is breaking the graph you can't really decide on an appropriate workaround. If the distrubution is what's causing the problem, it could be worth creating an issue with ChartsJS. A good work around would be to create a custom ticks function and hide the ones you don't want https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html. But that workaround isn't very useful until you nail down the technical problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have created a ticket on github for further assistance. If resolved on that side I will post a solution here.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6591

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, a chartjs dev has replied to my post here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6591

Looks like there are some issues in the current Chart.js version. Should be fixed in 2.9.