# Chartjs autoSkip true not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have implemented chartjs line chart in my app. I have set necessary variables to the chart. I have tried the solutions in stackoverflow. But the auto skip feature seems to be not working properly.(chartjs version => 2.9.3)

My html file

```
<canvas baseChart [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType"
                [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
</canvas>
```

My line chart options variable

```
lineChartOptions = {
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: true,
            }
          }
        };
```

I am loading 30 day items in the chart. The line chart is working. Only thing is labels for all 30 items are appearing even though I auto skipped.

Comment: In case you're using an older version of Chart.js, try to upgrade to a recent version (at lease 2.9.0) where the issue with `autskip` should be fixed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58526375/2358409)

Comment: I'm using 2.9 version

Comment: You should try to put **ticks** inside a **xAxes** or **yAxes** attributes.
More [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration)

Comment: @ChickenSoups yes, that's the correct answer.